# Get value from DocumentDb does not Work Web API 2 + c#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Web API 2 with Azure DocumentDb. 
I wrote this code to call the first document who match the string:

```
var x = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Product>((await this.collection).DocumentsLink)
             .Where(x => x.Name == "Hello1")
             .AsEnumerable()
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

but the result is always null.

the values of both SelfLink and DocumentsLink are:

```
(await this.collection).SelfLink = "dbs/h4IDAA==/colls/h4IDAPEiOAA=/";
(await this.collection).DocumentsLink= "dbs/h4IDAA==/colls/h4IDAPEiOAA=/docs/";
```

The code is connecting to DocumentDb right, and there is no problem with adding documents or updating.

what is the problem in my Code?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I have tested it on my side, here is my code snippet:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<GroupedSales>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId))
                    .Where(x => x.Site == 2)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    return Json(doc);
}
```

Result:

[image]

In order to troubleshoot this issue, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network trace as follows:

[image]

You need to check the `query` payload from your query request and the detailed response. For your query, I assumed that your `query` would look like `SELECT * FROM root WHERE (root[\"Name\"] =\"Hello1\")`. Also, you could use [DocumentDB Query Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-query-collections-query-explorer) in the Azure portal to check that whether your query could retrieve the expected document under your collection.